# Проблемы с wifi на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, intel

На днях обновил версию ubuntu, и с обновлением перестал работать wifi. В настройках пишут, что адаптеры wifi не найдены, но до обновления все работало.

```
uname -a
Linux computer 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)

ifconfig
enp0s20f0u3c4i2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.20.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.20.10.15
    inet6 fe80::d5e5:c7fa:3310:9835  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 2e:f0:a2:28:d7:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 3603  bytes 3226405 (3.2 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2769  bytes 455652 (455.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 54:e1:ad:49:97:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 319  bytes 29405 (29.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 319  bytes 29405 (29.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Надеюсь, поможете с решением проблемы. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже что было затронуто ядро системы, и как следствие потерлись настройки. У меня произошло тоже самое с моим адаптером, но у меня usb. Решилось просто: собрал модуль, установил, запустил.

UPD1

1. Убедиться что адаптер в списке присутствует. Команда - `lsusb`
2. Скачать драйвер который необходим. Разархивировать если необходимо. Перейти в разархивированный каталог
3. Далее консольный ввод
4. Повышаем права: `sudo -s`
5. Выполняем сборку модуля: `make`
6. Устанавливаем: `make install`
7. Включаем наш модуль: `modprobe "имя модуля"`
8. Проверяем: `ifconfig`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. В связи с этим новый вопрос: не подскажите как это сделать?